# Page Template missing in SitePages library

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I am working with sharepoint Online. I am quite new to this.

I created a page and added it as a template. From site -> Home, I can create new pages with this template. However, when I went to **SitePages** page library and try to create page, it gives me 3 options,

1. Wiki Page,
2. Webpart Page
3. Site Pages

And I can't find my template in Site Pages. It straightaway creates a page with the default template.

Can anyone help me with this.

**My Requirement: I want my users be able to create pages using custom templates in SitePages library**

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, site page does not support use page template, it is by design.

For more information, please refer to the "[Page templates in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873)".